# Conflict between UpdatePanel and RegisterStartupScript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a user control with some custom client side validation. When I have the user control on a page, it works no problem.  But if that page has a postback event (select a certain option from a dropdown, and more fields are displayed), my validation no longer seems to work. My validation is as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Type cstype = this.GetType();

    if (!Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, "ValidatorType"))
    {
        String DateValidator;
        DateValidator = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
        DateValidator += "function ValidateDate(source, args) {\n";
        DateValidator += "   var ddDay = document.getElementById(source.day);\n";
        DateValidator += "   var day = ddDay.selectedIndex;";
        DateValidator += "   var ddMonth = document.getElementById(source.month);\n";
        DateValidator += "   var month = ddMonth.selectedIndex;\n";
        DateValidator += "   var ddYear = document.getElementById(source.year);\n";
        DateValidator += "   var year = ddYear.selectedIndex;\n";
        DateValidator += "   if (day == 0 || month == 0 || year == 0)\n";
        DateValidator += "      args.IsValid = false;\n";
        DateValidator += "   else\n";
        DateValidator += "      args.IsValid = true;\n";
        DateValidator += "   }\n";
        DateValidator += "</script>";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "ValidatorType", DateValidator);
    }
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterExpandoAttribute(reqDueDate.ClientID, "month", ddMonth.ClientID);
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterExpandoAttribute(reqDueDate.ClientID, "day", ddDay.ClientID);
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterExpandoAttribute(reqDueDate.ClientID, "year", ddYear.ClientID);
}
```

I'm stumped.  Any advice?

**EDIT:**

Here is the User Control that I am using.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddMonth" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
   <asp:ListItem Value="">--Month--</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddDay" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Value="">--Day--</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddYear" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Value="">--Year--</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="reqDueDate" EnableClientScript="true" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required" CssClass="input-notification error png_bg" Display="Dynamic"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Comment: Any reason in particular this JavaScript cannot be added to the markup directly or from a file via `script` tag?

Comment: The Javascript is in a user control - so it's not always necessary. I have tried putting the Javascript in my js file, but it didn't do any difference.  It seems that the issue is that once the UpdatePanel fires, the original DOM is erased.

Comment: ~ what fires this validation script? Also if you're not using jQuery, you might want to look into [`add_endRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx). You can use this handler to rebind your validator to whatever it is that is calling your function

Comment: Not using jQuery - just using an ASP Button control. There is a CustomValidator attached to my user control that contains ClientValidationFunction="ValidateDate".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out, I needed to do 2 things.  Put an Update Panel around in my user code, and change the lines

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterExpandoAttribute(reqDueDate.ClientID, "day", ddDay.ClientID);
```

to

```
ScriptManager.RegisterExpandoAttribute(UpdatePanelDDD, reqDueDate.ClientID, "day", ddDay.ClientID, false);
```

Thanks all for your help and http://www.aspnetajaxtutorials.com/2010/09/customvalidator-registerexpandoattribut.html for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something *similar* to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

var btn = null;

var EndRequestHandler = function(sender, args) {
    btn = document.getElementById('<%= YourButton.ClientID %>');
    btn.onclick = ValidateDate;
};
</script>
```

or you could attach this to the form submit event in the client

**Edit**: the `endRequest` event is fired when MS Ajax completes any asyc request e.g. `UpdatePanel` updating the DOM. You can find more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx)

Comment: Not sure I follow the mixture of ASP (the first line after <script..) and the javascript here.

Comment: just setting an event handler to `endRequest` event, meaning, when an async request is complete, execute method `EndRequestHandler`

Comment: Not sure where this would fit into my User Control, which can't really target the submit button. I have added my code form my user control in the OP.

Comment: Just seen one of your comments on Adil's answer:  "but it's the objects that disappear from the DOM when the UpdatePanel refreshes that is the problem". Which objects disappear from the DOM?

Comment: The elements that I'm targeting to be validated:
e.g.
var ddDay = document.getElementById(source.day)
source.day is null after a updatepanel refresh.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not very familiar with `Page.ClientScript.RegisterExpandoAttribute(string, string, string)` so my guess is that it doesn't enter in your `if` condition in the `Page_Load` handler. When you're debugging, if you set a breakpoint at that method, does it go into that `if`?

Comment: It allows me to produce javascript that records the element ids of the controls within my user control - I need it in the case of having multiple instances of the user controls on the same page.  The javascript loads as requested, and have tried with the If statement and without - with no changes to the outcome.